# PHP & WebSockets

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I'm getting started with PHP & WebSockets.
I tried setting up a WebSocket connection, unsuccessfully.

main.js

```
const protocol = (() => {
  let protocol = "ws";
  if (location.protocol === "https") {
    protocol += "s";
  }
  return protocol + ":";
})();
const currentPath = location.href.replace(location.protocol, protocol);
const socket = new WebSocket(`${currentPath}php/player-info.php`);

socket.addEventListener("open", e => {
  socket.send("Hello");
});

socket.addEventListener("message", e => {
  console.log(e.data);
});
```

player-info.php

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) || die("Couldn't create socket");
$result = socket_bind($socket, $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], 500) || die("Couldn't bind to socket");
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) || die("Couldn't accept incoming connection");
$input = trim(socket_read($spawn, 1024) || die("Couldn't read input"));

$output = $input;
socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen($output)) || die("Couldn't write output");

socket_close($spawn);
socket_close($socket);
```

What I'm basically doing is opening the page that's linked with `main.js`.
When I look at the WebSocket network traffic, I see:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: WebSockets != Sockets

Comment: So how do I solve this problem?